# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am getting multiple errors in Xcode:

I just implemented this cocoa pod:

```
pod 'SwiftVideoBackground', '~> 3.0'
```

from [here](https://cocoapods.org/pods/SwiftVideoBackground). This pod is the reason for the error. Although after deleting it from the project and reading all other pods I found that the Twitter dependency still exists.

[image]

Pods im using:

```
pod 'RealmSwift'
pod 'Firebase'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Database'
pod 'FirebaseUI'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'Mapbox-iOS-SDK', '~> 4.9'
pod 'SwiftVideoBackground', '~> 3.0'
```

**What is this and how can I fix it?**

### **Update:**

Some more info as requested:

The large message before the message shown in the image reads:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_TWTRCoreOAuthSigningOAuthEchoHeaders", referenced from:
      -[TWTROAuthSigning OAuthEchoHeadersForRequestMethod:URLString:parameters:error:] in TwitterKit(TWTROAuthSigning.o)
...
```

At the end of the long message it says:

> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
> invocation)

Comment: Are you also trying to use Twitter Kit?

Comment: @rmaddy, I do not. I just assumed that it is part of another pod I have...

Comment: It appears one of the pods you are using has a dependency on [Twitter Kit](https://github.com/twitter/twitter-kit-ios) (I think that's the right one based on a Google search) but isn't correctly setup with the dependency.

Comment: @rmaddy what should I do about it then?

Comment: Figure out which pod is causing the problem and then file an issue report with the pod owner.

Comment: @rmaddy check update. I found that the pod I show at the beginning of the question causes the errors however I also see that the twitter dependency is still live even after getting rid of this pod.

Comment: Does the full error message tell you what is requiring those symbols?  I would have expected something telling you where they were referenced...maybe above the "Undefined symbol" lines you posted.

Comment: @PhillipMills does the update answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does, but also confuses me.  As far as I can tell both the caller and the missing symbol are related to TwitterKit.  (Maybe someone else can decode that.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by running:

```
pod outdated
```

and then

```
pod update
```